# Name Dependent Node?

Tags: ros, visp-auto-tracker, ros-hydro, primesense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use visp_auto_tracker this three cameras, the simplest way I see to this is to use three nodes. This does not work because for some reason visp_auto_tracker doesn't work if the node name is not "visp_auto_tracker". Here is my launch file:

```
<launch> 
    <!-- you can only use the debug display if name is "visp_auto_tracker" appearently nothing works if not visp_auto_tracker-->
    <node pkg="visp_auto_tracker" type="visp_auto_tracker" name="visp_auto_tracker" output="screen">
    <param name="model_path" type="string" value="$(find visp_auto_tracker)/models" />
    <param name="model_name" type="string" value="pattern" />
    <param name="debug_display" type="bool" value="True" />
    
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to="/primesense2/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw" to="/primesense2/rgb/image_raw"/>      
    <!--<remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info_2" to="/primesense1/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw_2" to="/primesense1/rgb/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info_3" to="/primesense3/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw_3" to="/primesense3/rgb/image_raw"/>-->
  </node>
    <node pkg="visp_auto_tracker" type="visp_auto_tracker" name="visp_auto_tracker_ps1" output="screen">
    <param name="model_path" type="string" value="$(find visp_auto_tracker)/models" />
    <param name="model_name" type="string" value="pattern" />
    <param name="debug_display" type="bool" value="True" />
          
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to="/primesense1/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw" to="/primesense1/rgb/image_raw"/>
  </node>
    <node pkg="visp_auto_tracker" type="visp_auto_tracker" name="visp_auto_tracker_ps3" output="screen">
    <param name="model_path" type="string" value="$(find visp_auto_tracker)/models" />
    <param name="model_name" type="string" value="pattern" /> 
    <param name="debug_display" type="bool" value="True" />
          
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to="/primesense3/rgb/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw" to="/primesense3/rgb/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I modified a different version of the tracker to work with three cameras, but it has stability issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131766/name-dependent-node?????/) by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-21**:
I don't know the package, but it sounds like either a serious bug to be fixed or just wrong configuration/setup? Maybe test just one node with a different name or grep the sources for the name - it shouldn't be hardcoded anywhere besides init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I was a bit fail here, the ramps point to the default name not the used. :P

---

Originally posted by [AlphaOne](https://answers.ros.org/users/4021/alphaone/) with karma: 141 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0